installation location of kubelet, kubeschedule, and etcd after purge remove
To re-install my local cluster using kubeadm, I ran following commands:
sudo apt-get purge -y kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni  kubelet kube-apiserver kube-scheduler kube-controller-manager kube-proxy
sudo apt-get autoremove -y

and then reboot my machine.
The wired thing is that I still find a number of kube process using ps:
(base) ➜  ~ ps -ef | grep kube 
root        9198    8816  3 12:46 ?        00:01:11 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock --node-ip=172.23.0.2 --node-labels= --pod-infra-container-image=registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9 --provider-id=kind://docker/kind/kind-control-plane --fail-swap-on=false --cgroup-root=/kubelet
root        9480    9312  2 12:46 ?        00:00:52 kube-controller-manager --allocate-node-cidrs=true --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --cluster-name=kind --cluster-signing-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cluster-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key --controllers=*,bootstrapsigner,tokencleaner --enable-hostpath-provisioner=true --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf --leader-elect=true --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/16 --use-service-account-credentials=true
root        9513    9313  0 12:46 ?        00:00:11 kube-scheduler --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf --leader-elect=true
root        9550    9352  6 12:46 ?        00:02:13 kube-apiserver --advertise-address=172.23.0.2 --allow-privileged=true --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --runtime-config= --secure-port=6443 --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/16 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
root        9557    9344  3 12:46 ?        00:01:06 etcd --advertise-client-urls=https://172.23.0.2:2379 --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --client-cert-auth=true --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd --experimental-initial-corrupt-check=true --experimental-watch-progress-notify-interval=5s --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://172.23.0.2:2380 --initial-cluster=kind-control-plane=https://172.23.0.2:2380 --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key --listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://172.23.0.2:2379 --listen-metrics-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2381 --listen-peer-urls=https://172.23.0.2:2380 --name=kind-control-plane --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --peer-client-cert-auth=true --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --snapshot-count=10000 --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
root       10082   10017  0 12:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=kind-control-plane

But I could not find these files (e.g., kube-proxy, kubelet, kube-apiserver, and kube-scheduler) in the directories, as root:
(base) ➜  ~ ll /usr/bin/kubelet                
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/kubelet': No such file or directory
(base) ➜  ~ kubectl 
zsh: command not found: kubectl
(base) ➜  ~ 
(base) ➜  ~ sudo kube-apiserver --help            
sudo: kube-apiserver: command not found
(base) ➜  ~ cd /usr/bin          
(base) ➜  bin ls kubelet 
ls: cannot access 'kubelet': No such file or directory
(base) ➜  bin ll kube-controller-manager                
ls: cannot access 'kube-controller-manager': No such file or directory
(base) ➜  bin ll kube-apiserver                       
ls: cannot access 'kube-apiserver': No such file or directory

Could anyone help explain how these processes are launched? Thanks.

@ Xu Shijie  Have you gone through my solution & the answer helps to resolve your issue, if not let me know, I am happy to assist you further.

The answer to this question is that these kube* processors are mapped from a docker container kindest/node:v1.26.0. After stop the container, these processors disappear.

The challenge you have is that, even though you used kubeadm purge and apt-get autoremove to delete the kubernetes packages, the systemd services that handle these processes are still running and trying to start them.
It implies that using apt-get-purge, you managed to completely remove the kubernetes binaries like kubelet, kube-apiserver among others. However, it is likely that the system services for managing these binaries are still enabled and strive to run them, although their files are missing.
/etc /systemd/system/ is a typical location where the systemd services for kubernetes components can be found.
To deal with this situation use sudo systemctl stop kubelet kube-apiserver kube- controller- manager kube- scheduler kube- proxy etcd to terminate all those running service processes.
Also think about disabling them.To disable any of these services just type sudo systemctl disable kubelet kube-apiserbver kube- controller- manager kube-scheduler jube -proxy etcd so as not to enable them again after booting up your PC.
In addition, check if there are any remaining configuration files or folders concerning Kubernetes after stopping it. These will be placed in directories such as /etc/kubernetes or /var/lib/kubernetes.
If you adhere to these instructions well enough by either properly disabling all the major leftover Kubernetes services or through cleaning up everything then preparing afresh for reinstallation process via Kubeadm.

I finally found  a file snap.kubelet.daemon.service under /etc/systemd/system, and then systemctl stop/disable  snap.kubelet.daemon.service and restart solves my problem.

Updated: Seems the problem still there event after remove snap.kubelet.daemon.service. After restart, the kube* processors come out after a short time..and these processes occupy 20% CPU times..
